# Setting up state for an Angular 8 application by url and ngxs combined

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular8, ngxs

I am developing an Angular 8 application where I use [ngsx](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/store) for keeping states such as logged user, its configuration over the entire application,and etc. I have a new challenge that I am trying to handle which is the following:

> Our QA should always be able to turn on and off the mock state by URL using ?isMock=true/false inside URL

How can I bind angular routing with ngsx in order to achieve it?

Comment: You shouldn't "bind" routing with NGXS. You can do it the same way as you would without NGXS. Router plugin is a bit buggy, stay away from it :)

Comment: @overthesanity: I am looking for code snippet to forward. Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

check NGXS Router Plugin, sounds like it might fix your issue:
https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/router